# Hide ACF Field When Two Other Fields are Empty

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

On my page, I have a list of staff members as a CPT. Some of them have additional certifications and/or a bio.

How can I include a "read more" link but **only** if either the field for certification OR the field for bio has content?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.  If you're looking for or as you mentioned you can just check the certification field, if it has a value you show the link.  If it doesn't check the bio field.  Has value show link.

```
<?php

$certs = get_field( "cert_field" ); // add field name here for certifications
$bio = get_field( "bio_field" ); // add field name here for bio

<?php if($certs) : ?> <!-- Check if cert field has value -->

    <a href="#">Read More</a> <!-- If true it will show read more -->

<?php else if($bio) : ?> // Else check for bio field

    <a href="#">Read More</a> <!-- If true it will show read more -->

<?php endif; ?>
```